# IOS Bluetooth keyboard - Special keys (ctrl, shift, arrow) in browser

Tags: ios, browser, keyboard, modifier-key, bluetooth-keyboard

Is there a browser app (or keyboard app?) that supports sending ctrl, shift etc keys to the webpage correctly? You can test it by http://keycode.info . Safari on ios do not handle ctrl, shift, alt and arrow keys as like in other platform.
I want to have better experiences when using sites like repl.it. However even though I have my Bluetooth keyboard with my iPad, I still encounter many problems like unable to navigate cursor using arrow keys. I think if that browser exists could resolve my problems.